# Django: unable to login with new users

Tags: python, django

When i make a new user, I can not login. It only works for the user that was set up when running 'createsuperuser' command.

I have also noticed it does not hash the password. It is stored as clear text.

I have tried creating it in admin and my user form but both do not work.

login.html

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" method="post"
    action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                       required="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileCreate(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    success_url = '/sites/list'
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
    site = models.ManyToManyField(Site, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please show the code for UserProfileForm.

Comment: Added UserProfileForm

Comment: Your user form is not hashing the password in the database correctly. See [the example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should transform your UserProfileCreate class with the following :

```
class UserProfileCreate(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    success_url = '/sites/list'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.set_password(self.object.password)
        return super(UserProfileCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

It will hash the user password.